# SQL: How to use the value of query as a field of another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

user_object:

```
  id |  group | object_id 
-----+--------+------------
  1  |  admin | 30
  2  |  user  | 40
  3  |  user  | 50
```

object_permissions:

```
  id  | name | user   | admin 
------+------+--------+--------
  30  | foo  | false  | true
  40  | bar  | false  | false
  50  | baz  | true   | true
```

I hope the example above helps.  I want something like the following.  I figure if it is even possible there will be subqueries and possibly an eval.

```
SELECT u.id
     , o.name
     , o.<u.group>        as permissions
FROM   user_object        u
JOIN   object_permissions o
       ON (u.object_id = o.id);
----------------------------
  id |  name | permissions
-----+-------+--------------
  1  |  foo  | true
  2  |  bar  | false
  3  |  baz  | true
```

Comment: `user` and `group` are [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in every SQL standard as well as in PostgreSQL. *Never* use them as identifiers or you may run into unexpected errors.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter that may be true, but this is only an example, not actual data.  Still, that is important to note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming admin/user are the only values appearing in group column of user_object, try this:

```
SELECT u.id
     , o.name
     , CASE WHEN u.group = 'admin'
          THEN o.admin 
          ELSE o.user
       END AS permissions
FROM   user_object        u
JOIN   object_permissions o
       ON (u.object_id = o.id);
```

Comment: They aren't, but if I didn't even think about using CASE statement.  This might do +1